# Get the strings before the comma with R

Tags: string, r, split, extract

I am a beginner with R. Now, I have a vector in a data.frame like this

```
city
Kirkland,
Bethesda,
Wellington,
La Jolla,
Berkeley,
Costa, Evie KW172NJ
Miami,
Plano,
Sacramento,
Middletown,
Webster,
Houston,
Denver,
Kirkland,
Pinecrest,
Tarzana,
Boulder,
Westfield,
Fair Haven,
Royal Palm Beach, Fl
Westport,
Encino,
Oak Ridge,
```

I want to clean it. What I want is all the city names before the comma. How can I get the result in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with a bit of regexp :

```
cities <- gsub("^(.*?),.*", "\\1", df$city)
```

This one works, too :

```
cities <- gsub(",.*$", "", df$city)
```

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest almost exactly the same... `gsub( "^(.+),.*" , "\\1" , df$city )`

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, you can use `strsplit`

```
> x <- c("London, UK", "Paris, France", "New York, USA")
> sapply(strsplit(x, ","), "[", 1)
[1] "London"   "Paris"    "New York"
```

Comment: What if you were to separate after every , like for example `AAA, BBB, C 1.05` to `AAA`, `BBB`, `C 1.05`?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy, you can use `unlist(strsplit(c("AAA, BBB, C 1.05"), ","))`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `regexpr` to find the position of the first comma in each element and use `substr` to snip them at this:

```
x <- c("London, UK", "Paris, France", "New York, USA")

substr(x,1,regexpr(",",x)-1)
[1] "London"   "Paris"    "New York"
```

Answer (score 4):

If the this was a column in a dataframe, we can use tidyverse.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c("London, UK", "Paris, France", "New York, USA")
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x %>% separate(x, c("A","B"), sep = ',')
        A       B
1   London      UK
2    Paris  France
3 New York     USA
```

Comment: separate is in the tidyr package
`tidyr::separate(x, c("A","B"), sep = ',')` drops the x column
`tidyr::separate(x, c("A","B"), sep = ',', remove = TRUE)` keeps the x column

Comment: What if you were to separate after every `,` like for example `AAA, BBB, C 1.05` to `AAA`, `BBB`, `C 1.05`?

Answer (score 2):

This works as well:

```
x <- c("London, UK", "Paris, France", "New York, USA")

library(qdap)
beg2char(x, ",")

## > beg2char(x, ",")
## [1] "London"   "Paris"    "New York"
```