# Extracting a sub-string from a string in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a data-frame which has a column with strings like this `Live by Night | Buy or rent on Blu-ray, DVD or digital`. I want to keep the string only before the `|` symbol. so the sub-string result that I want from the above one is "Live by Night"
Thanks in advance for your valuable inputs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895050/using-gsub-to-extract-character-string-before-white-space-in-r  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320966/get-the-strings-before-the-comma-with-r or exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291794/extract-string-before A little research goes a long way.

Answer (score 3):

One option is `sub` to match zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by `|` (metacharacter, so we need to escape to read it as the literal character, otherwise it is meant for `OR`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s*\\|.*", "", str1)
#[1] "Live by Night"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "Live by Night | Buy or rent on Blu-ray, DVD or digital"
```